# How to get default printer name in local machine using java script?

Tags: javascript

How to get default printer name in local machine using java script

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make use of ActiveXObject like this:

```
function getDfaultPrinter()
{
   var obj;
   obj=new ActiveXObject("Project1.UserControl1");
   alert(obj.PrinterName);
}
```

*Do note that you need to install the ActiveX on the client or on server where you want to know the default printer name.*

Answer (score 1):

you could use [nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/printer) too:

```
var printer = require('printer');

console.log('default printer name: ' + (printer.getDefaultPrinterName() || 'is not defined on your computer'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Its not an available API endpoint. Only browser that could support it would be IE using ActiveX and even that is disabled by default on most new systems.